# Can I reuse the name of an old arcade game?

Tags: legal, copyright

I've done an indie remake of an old arcade game from 1980.

Can I use its name? I thought copyright expired after 25 years but I could be wrong, hence this question.

Comment: Seems I post this comment about three times a week, but..  Definitely ask a qualified attorney in your area before making assumptions about what is or isn't illegal.  It's really not worth risking fines and/or jail time for violating the local IP laws in your area on the basis of any answers you get here or anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: @Maik tell that to OpenTTD?

Comment: Also **important to note** is that a copyright is quite different from a trademark.  In North America, copyright lasts for some period of time after the author's death (possibly 50 years), but a trademark, which has to be renewed, can last as long as renewal fees are paid (and the mark isn't struck down for some reason such as through litigation, getting adopted as a natural part of the language, etc.).

Comment: @trevor agreed but this one is *so* obviously "uh, no, don't do that"

Comment: @Jeff: Hardly. A trademark from an old arcade game is very likely to have lapsed, switched areas of trade, or simply never have been claimed.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, it may be an obvious risk to *most* people on SE sites, but seeing the occasional *13-year old programmer* posts, I'm not sure if *everyone* realizes the dangers :) (And as @Joe Wreschnig said, a trademark may or may not still be valid.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments (except @Maik's). I'm an indie dev so I'm not going to make megabucks out of this (most likely nothing), so the attorney option is unattractive. I've  checked with the US trade mark search engine and the one I'm after (Crazy Balloon) isn't listed.  It's difficult to know what's 'due diligence'.  I'm thinking I'd be satisfied with a possible cease-and-desist letter as it'd be no great hardship to change the name of my indie game(s).

Comment: @Steve I'm not a lawyer, but if I were to use that name, I'd at least show this to my lawyer: http://www.trademarkia.com/crazy-balloon-73275070.html

Comment: In all seriousness, @Steve Dunn - why not just create a new name? It's not *that* hard, and avoids *potential* trouble. Also, [Crazy Balloon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Balloon) was updated and re-released in 2005, so I *really* suggest finding a new name. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're asking about more than the *name*, if you re-made the actual *game* (rhyme unintended). In the US, [copyright has been constantly extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_extension#Duration), and is now the author's life + 75 years - so no, the game is still copyrighted.

And the name is covered by *[trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_infringement)*, not copyright (which also would not have expired - I don't think it does expire). If your name is *identical*, then yes it's a trademark violation. If it's *similar*, then it depends - some companies are more litigious than others (See [Edge Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Games), who sued anyone that had a game with the word *edge* in it, like "Mirror's Edge" by EA.

Activision had to license the name [Civilization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_%28series%29) from Avalon Hill, maker of a board game with the same name.

Comment: Trademarks last for as long as the trade name is in any sort of commercial use or planned future use.  Copyright will cover the game's logo, and that copyright will still be in effect.

Comment: @Trevor Powell:  Trademarks must be renewed as well (there are fees involved with this).  "Planned future use" can be problematic because marks not in use are usually much easier for another party to contest.  You have the right idea though, so +1.

Comment: Note that game clones are not a violation of copyright. Making a copy of a game executable violates copyright, as does using someone's source code without their permission, but game mechanics cannot be copyrighted. They might be patentable.

Comment: @Gregory: I would avoid blanket statements like that. "Sweat of the brow" is enough to establish copyright in some European jurisdictions, which easily covers things like damage tables. I am also not convinced that more abstract works like (a complete copy of) fighting game movesets would not be covered, as there's clear creativity/originality there.

Comment: @Joe: You're right. What I said is generally true in the US, but the boundary between copyrightable works and patentable methods is fuzzy.

Answer (score 3):

The only safe way to do this is to buy or license the rights for the game from the current owner. This can be expensive and time-consuming. The rights holder might ask for a fixed fee plus royalties, and as an indie game developer, that's likely going to be more than you expect to earn.

On the other hand, if the original game was produced by a very small company or an individual, you can probably contact them and get permission to do the remake pretty easily.

If you do a remake of a classic game, the rights holder can sue you and has a reasonable chance of winning. Tetris Holding is renowned for this.

If you just use the name in an unrelated game whose name is not currently being used for any commercial purpose, the rights holder can still sue you to bankruptcy.

It's slightly safer if you are not selling the game, I think. More likely to avoid notice, and the potential fines might be smaller. But you're only safe if you get an agreement with the rights holder.